# Accessing all documents from drive using Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive API in order to access the documents of a user from their drive. Following the instructions here https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Using the scope **https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive** at the time of authentication.

Users are authorizing Google app of our system to access their documents but the problem is that they not getting all documents from their drive when they are trying to access the documents from their drive in our system. (Though they are getting a few documents from their drive). Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

We need to see the specific call to /files/list.

Some things to check ...

- Are the missing files owned by the user?
- Is there a nextPage in the response that you are not following?
- Is there a query in your /files/list?

Comment: Are the missing files owned by the user? 

YES

Is there a nextPage in the response that you are not following?

YES , i am checking for the nextPage token. Here's the code 


    do {
      val files = request.execute
      result ++= (files.getItems)
      request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken)
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0)

Is there a query in your /files/list?

This is how i am fetching the files :

service.files.list

Where service is of type com.google.api.services.drive.Drive